# The getter 'future' isn't defined for the type 'StorageUploadTask'

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, file-upload

I'm trying to implement image picker and upload images to Firebase storage for user's profile page.
It gives an error like "The getter 'future' isn't defined for the type 'StorageUploadTask'.
Try importing the library that defines 'future', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'future'."

```
     class _SelectprofilepicPageState extends State<SelectprofilepicPage> {
     File newProfilePic;

     Future getImage() async {
     var tempImage = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     setState(() {
     newProfilePic = tempImage;
     });
     }

      uploadImage() {
      var randomno = Random(25);
      final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('profilepics/${randomno.nextInt(5000).toString()}.jpg');
StorageUploadTask task = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(newProfilePic);

task.future.then((value) {
  userManagement.updateProfilePicture(value.downloadUrl.toString()).then((val) {
    //Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
  });
}).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
}
```

Comment: `task` is probably already a future. have you tried `task.then(...` ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy yes after I removed that 'future' it gives an error on 'then'

Comment: which firebase storage version is this?

Comment: @PeterHaddad It's firebase_storage: 3.1.6 I had to use it because it was depend my older firebase_auth packages so this is the newest one who can fit with my project

Comment: what is the error on then?

Comment: it gives an error about task.'future' part. According to message, the getter 'future'  isn't defined for StorageUploadTask. I used this repo, if you want you can check.  https://github.com/rajayogan/flutter-firebasestarter